# Apache: how to block access to files like Gruntfile.js, package.json, etc?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have Gruntfile.js and package.json and folders node_modules and .git.
I want to block access to those files and folders. In the app I have index.php as the door to every non file/folder request

Here is in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

and in index.php

```
if (isset($_GET['page'] && !file_exists($views.$_GET['page'])) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    include $views.'404.php';
}
```

So It would be better if those private files were shown as 404 with the respective view

Comment: Do you want to block the `node_modules` directory *and* everything in it, or just root access to that directory?

Comment: @MikeRockett everything

Answer (score -2):

My solution was to use a simple RewriteRule to redirect to 404 view from index.php for every private file and folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Gruntfile\.js$ index.php?page=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^package\.json$ index.php?page=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^.git/.*$ index.php?page=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^node_modules/.*$ index.php?page=404 [L]
```

Though I think that these kind of files need to be in a root folder, and the index.php in a subfolder like `public_html` which is the only public

This solution even works with uppercase and mixed letters. i.e.:

```
pacKagE.json
gruntfile.js
.GIT/
```

Comment: This does redirect request to the folders from browser, but it also redirects the include requests in `<script>` and `<link>`